# Graphic glitch of the scrolling on Gnome 3.36.8 Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: graphics, scrolling

when I scroll in an application on Ubuntu 20.04.5 there is a "break" of the movement on a line at a certain height. I noticed that the problem also occurs, watching a video on Youtube or if any element moves on that line this problem occurs. The problem only occurs when the screen is rotated (90 °, 180 ° or 270 °) and since my computer is a 2in1 convertible it is quite annoying.
I use an Acer Spin 3 notebook with Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (I use Gnome 3.36.8) with Windows 10 in dual-boot.
OS Details:
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
How can I solve?
[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWR67.jpg)
Thanks
sim.dll

Comment: Typical wrong GPU driver issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by lowering the display refresh rate to 60Hz.
Thanks